# ERLANG SSH_SFTP issue on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)

Tags: ssh, erlang, sftp

I have written a client application over ERLANG ssh_sftp that upload's the file to the remote servers. For the file's that are below 1GB the application is working fine, however for bigger files I get the following error "Bad packet length" from the server & server closes the connection.

The OTP version I am using is :Erlang/OTP 19 [erts-8.0]

I am sure its not the network issue since I tried to send the file to localhost & got the same error.

One important thing is when I tried to compile the application on Erlang R16B03-1 (erts-5.10.4) in that case also my upload got failed but the reason was different : "Protocol error: expected packet type 30, got 93"

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug on OTP-19.0 so I upgraded the OTP to OTP-19.3 and application worked like charm :)